# Loading and Saving from a file c++ highscore function

Tags: c++

I have a game that I have created. I want to implement a function that loads and saves  high scores. At first when there is no text file (in my case `highscore.txt`), once created I want to print 0 to the file. If it is there on load I want it to load the highscore from the previous playing of the game. How would I go about this?

Here is my code:

```
void filewrite(){

    int n;

    FILE *FPtr;
    FPtr = fopen("highscore.txt","w+");//open file
    if (FPtr == NULL){
    fprintf (FPtr, "%d" , highscore);
    rewind(FPtr);
    }
    fscanf(FPtr,"%d",&n);//scan file for integer


    if (n < score){
        if(highscore < score ){
            if(end==true){
                fprintf (FPtr, "%d" , score);//print the score to file if it is higher than the score already there
                rewind(FPtr);//rewind the file, so pointer starts at begining
                fscanf(FPtr,"%d",&highscore);//scan file for int
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(FPtr);//close pointer to file

}
```

fopen seems to overwrite what was in the file already and leaves it blank

Comment: This looks more like C to me. Also, what is the question?

Comment: You likely want to change the condition if (FPtr == NULL) to if (FPtr != NULL). Now, what is the actual problem and question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The steps you should take are:

- Try and open the file for reading.
- If that failed then open for writing, write 0, and then open for reading.
- Read the value in the file and test as needed.

Comment: Or:
* Try to read the file. If it doesn't exist, pretend it contained 0.
* Compare the value read to the new score.
* If the new score is higher, write it to the file.
(If someone scored 0, the file won't get created, but the net result is the same.)

Comment: Cheers, been working on this for too long, so the simple things you don't think of. Appreciate it :)